# Query and Database performance when used with JpaRepository findAll() vs native query using JpaRepository

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a spring boot project where i am having two functions for JPA on which i need to figure out which function will perform better and put less pressure on database query performance and utilise Hibernate caching. Please guide on which query to use.

My Repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomersRepository
        extends JpaRepository<CustomersEntity, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE c_mobile = ?1")
    CustomersEntity findcustomerByMobile(String mobileNo);

    @Override
    List<CustomersEntity> findAll();
}
```

My Service class:

```
@Scope("request")
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements ICustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomersRepository customersRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean findCustomerByMobile1(long mobileNo) {

        CustomersEntity customersEntity = customersRepository.findcustomerByMobile(mobileNo);

        if (customersEntity != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean findCustomerByMobile2(long mobileNo) {

        List<CustomersEntity> entityList = customersRepository.findAll();

        for (CustomersEntity entity : entityList) {
            if (entity.getcMobile() == mobileNo) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely the first one. Because in second query all mobilenos loaded in session and comes into application side, alse the databse has to load all records which is not necessary.
In first one just one record load in database and we don&#39;t need to iterate over the list to find that mobileno.
I think if mobile table has many records such as 100000 or more, the second query doesn&#39;t work at all, plus , after a good time for warm-up in application, hibernate caching works fine.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to download all records from the database to your app and then filtering them. With thousands of records it will slow down.

Instead you should create an index on `c_mobile` field then use just like this simple method:

```
public interface CustomerRepo extends JpaRepository<CustomersEntity, Long> {
    CustomersEntity findByMobileNo(String mobileNo);
}
```

It will work in a flash (with index).

More info about building query methods you can find [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods).